# On the usage of many train/test split ratios

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, econometrics, descriptive-statistics, train-test-split

Is there any benefit in evaluating model performance under different train/test ratios?

To me, this sounds kind of nonsense because of these reasons:

1. I cannot access such a parameter when the model is in production, making it pointless to have it in a model selection process;
2. How should I interpret a change from one ratio to another? I cannot say "...because the performances are stable across different ratios therefore, my pipeline is more robust.". The test sample will be of different sizes preventing any meaningful testing, especially in classification.

Of course, It may be a confirmation bias of mine. If someone has good reasons, plus some article pointing to that, I will be more than happy to read those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> any benefit in evaluating model performance under different train/test ratios?

Since different train/test ratios lead to different train set sizes, you can evaluate a somewhat special version of the model's *learning curve*. I.e., the performance as function of train set size.
Somewhat special here means that for small training sets the curve you get is an approximation to how your training algorithm behaves on data sets of the given size and problem - but as the split ratio approaches "all training" the curve gets closer and closer to the particular realization of one data set.
In the paper linked below you can find diagrams where we compare this with what is usually meant by learning curve (expected performance across independent data sets of given training size).

However, I've found for the type and size of data I work with that there is limited if any practically useful information to be gained from this. People try to use this technique to do sample size planning in the sense that they try to estimate what performance gain can be expected from adding more training cases. The uncertainty on this is IMHO far too large for practical purposes, though.

For details see [Beleites, C. and Neugebauer, U. and Bocklitz, T. and Krafft, C. and Popp, J.: Sample size planning for classification models. Anal Chim Acta, 2013, 760, 25-33.

DOI: 10.1016/j.aca.2012.11.007](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.aca.2012.11.007)
[accepted manuscript on arXiv: 1211.1323](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.1323)

---

One exception may be that if you are in algorithm development rather than developing a model for production use, doing this over a number of different data sets may yield insight into how "data-hungry" the algorithm is.

---

You'd want to evaluate a number of splits per split ratio in any case to get an idea of how stable the behaviour for that split size is.

Comment: I did not think about the model learning curve from that perspective! Indeed very interesting, especially the sample size planning concept.

Answer (score 4):

To compare performance using different train-test splits you will need to use a performance metric that accounts for the different sizes and normalises in a way that is "scale free" with respect to the test sample size.  That should take care of the main problem you mention in your question.

Now, having said this, you should exhibit due scepticism with respect to comparing different train-test splits, particularly if you end up "optimising" over the split proportion.  If you fit and test the model under a range of different splits and then optimise the test performance by searching over this range then you have *used the test data for model fitting* and so it is no longer test data.  This pollutes the entire train-test split and means that in some cases you no longer have any genuine test data.  The result ---as in other cases where no test data is used--- is overfitting of the model and performance metrics that are not respresentative of the performance of the model when deployed on separate test data.

Comment: You are right in the case of using normalized performance metrics. But in a classification task, do such metrics exist? For example, an AUROC or AUPCR will be highly affected by the sample size as this will create sharper decreases the less observation there are.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, my opinions are:

1. Try different train/test radio is meaningful. Because, if you can find the lower bound or your ratio, this can show how sufficient your model is to some extent.
2. Finding the best radio for your model, can also lead the users to split their datasets.

However, I also think this radio does not make as much sense as one thought it would. Because radio is not universal. For example, suppose we have the best-performing radio is 7:3, but that doesn't mean that you can use this ratio on a very small data set and get the model to perform as expected, so I think it makes more sense to experiment and try to find the minimum amount of data your model needs.

Comment: You're right Allonsy, regarding point 1. but in that case, would it not be better to use a Montecarlo Cross Validation, keeping the same ratio? In that case, I will also have an idea of my model performance. Your idea of finding the minimal amount of data that gives a "decent" model is good. But aren't we exploiting the test set for this? Which is generally not a good thing to do.

Comment: Hi Marco. In my opinion, I think that both k-fold and Montecarlo are ok. But remember that if you use Montecarlo, do more experiments.  For finding the "decent" model, my opinion is that, trying to reduce your total data amount, the ratio can be a hassle, but it depends on the model, choose a ratio you think is fair and train it. At least you can be sure that your model performs well with this ratio and amount of data. But there is not much point in finding an "exact" amount of data, I think you just need to reduce the size of the data appropriately.